# Application of the monotone convergence theorem to a product measure

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to understand the poof of a theorem in a book. Consider the
product measure $\mu = \times_{n = 1}^{\infty} \mu_n$ on
$\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ where $\mu_n$ are finite measures on $\mathbb{R}$. Let
$x \in \ell_2$. How does one conclude by the monotone convergence theorem that
$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^{\infty}} \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} x_k^2 \mu \left(
   \mathrm{d} x \right) = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} x_k^2 \mu_k
   \left( \mathrm{d} x_k \right) $

**My attempt:**

The sequence $s_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n x_k^2$ is monotone since $s_n \leqslant
s_{n + 1}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \int_{\mathbb{R}^{\infty}} \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} x_k^2 \mu \left(
  \mathrm{d} x \right) & = & \int_{\mathbb{R}^{\infty}} \lim_{n \rightarrow
  \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^n x_k^2 \mu \left( \mathrm{d} x \right)\\
  &  &
  \text{by the MCT}\\
  & = & \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{\infty}} \sum_{k =
  1}^n x_k^2 \mu \left( \mathrm{d} x \right)\\
  & = & \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \sum_{k = 1}^n x_k^2
  \mu_1 \times \cdots \times \mu_n \left( \mathrm{d} x_1 \cdots \mathrm{d} x_k
  \right)\\
  & = & \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^n \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} x_k^2
  \mu_1 \times \cdots \times \mu_n \left( \mathrm{d} x_1 \cdots \mathrm{d} x_k
  \right)\\
  & = &  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^n
  \int_{\mathbb{R}} x_k^2 \mu_k \left( \mathrm{d} x_k \right)\\
  & = & \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} x_k^2 \mu_k \left(
  \mathrm{d} x_k \right)
\end{eqnarray*}
Is this the correct way of writing the proof in a very detailed fashion? Am I
jumping some logical hurdles here (for instance when writing $\mu(\mathrm{d}x)$ at the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second line doesn't look quite right. Not that the sequence $f_n \colon\mathbb R^{\infty} \to [0,\infty)$ given by $f_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2$ is monotone. So you have
$$ \int_{\mathbb R^\infty} \lim f_n(x) \,d\mu
  = \lim \int_{\mathbb R^\infty} f_n(x)\, d\mu $$
with an integral over $\mathbb R^\infty$. If the $\mu_k$ are probability measures (which I will assume in the following and you also seem to do so), we have by Fubini that is equals 
$$ \lim \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{\mathbb R} x_k^2 d\mu_k = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{\mathbb R} x_k^2 \, d\mu_k. $$

Comment: Thanks martini! Is there a standard reference about the Fubini theorem in a countable setting?

Comment: @learner You just have Fubini for $n+1$ factors $\mathbb R^\infty \cong \mathbb R \times \cdots \mathbb R \times \mathbb R^\infty_{\text{rest}}$ where $\mathbb R^\infty_{\text{rest}}$ has the coordinates $(x_{n+1},x_{n+2},\ldots)$, as the integrand does not depend on these, we have the integral over this equal to the constant integrand, as $\mu_{\text{rest}} = \bigotimes_{k=n+1}^\infty \mu_k$ is a probability measure.